# i have a mongoose schema can any one please tell me how i can insert data into it through create method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

this is my schema i want to know how can i add data through create method in the
qurestion field please help

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const QuizSchema = mongoose.Schema({
course: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "course"
},
topic: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "topic"
},
starttime: {
    type: Date,
    require:true,
},
endtime: {
    type: Date,
    require: true,

},
qusetions: [
    {
        qustiontext: {
            type: String,
        },
        correctans: {
            type: String,

        },
        ansoptions: [
            {
                anstext: {
                    type: String
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],

students: [
    {
        student: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "student"
        },
        selectedans: [
            {
                anstext: {
                    type: String
                }
            }]}],
```

},
{
timestamps:true,
});

const Quizmodel=mongoose.model("quiz" ,QuizSchema);
module.exports=Quizmodel;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For inserting data into the `question` field in one document, see the code below.

```js
// fetch the quiz document you want to edit.
const quiz = await Quizemodel.findById(_id);

// edit question field.
quiz.questions.push({qustiontext: '', correctans: '', ...})

// save the document
await quiz.save()
```

For creating documents and saving them to the database see the code below:

```js
const quiz = new Quizmodel({
 topic: ...,
 starttime: ...,
 ...
});
quiz.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved!
});
```

or with the `create` method:

```js
Quizmodel.create({
 topic: ...,
 starttime: ...,
 ...
}, function (err, small) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved!
});
```

more details at [mongoose documents](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)!

Comment: actually i want to to add questions on create event i just watn to know how to add data into the schema only for the questions field while  i am creating a quiz without creating and then updating the document seperately